# How to send USDT with Multi-signature feature in TronWeb

Tags: tron, tronweb

I saw the [official document](https://developers.tron.network/docs/multi-signature-example-process-flow#3-select-permission-and-create-transaction). But it is only for transferring trx.

`usdtContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).send()` can not use the multi-signature feature.

I alse tried to use `triggerSmartContract`, here is code:

```
        const transferData = await tronWeb.transactionBuilder.triggerSmartContract(
            contractAddress,
            'transfer(address,uint256)',
            {
                feeLimit: 100000000,
                callValue: 0,
                tokenId: 0,
                from: multiSigAddress,
                contractAddress: contractAddress,
                PermissionId: 2,
            },
            [
                { type: 'address', value: toAddress },
                { type: 'uint256', value: amount },
            ],
        );

        var signedTransaction = await tronWeb.trx.multiSign(transferData, privateKey, 2);
        const result = await tronWeb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction);
```

But it has an error: `Invalid transaction provided`

Is there any code example for me? thanks.